# TypeError: foundUser is not iterable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, mern

unable to iterate the user data

```
router.post("/signin",(req,res)=>{
    const{email,password}=req.body;
    if(!email||!password){
       return res.status(404).json({error:"enter all the feilds"})
    }
   
        User.findOne({email:email}).then(foundUser=>{
            if(!foundUser){
               return res.status(422).json({error:"user not found"})
            }
           
                bcrypt.compare(password,foundUser.password).then(match=>{
                    if(match){
                       
                       // res.json({message:"signin sucessfully"})
                        const token=jwt.sign({_id:foundUser._id},JWT_SECRET)
                        const [_id,name,email]=foundUser //here is the error
                        return  res.json({token,user:foundUser._id})
                    }
                    
                       return res.status(422).json({message:"email and password doesnt match"})
                    
                })
            
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    
})
```

error:
(node:27268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: foundUser is not iterable
at G:\courses\implementation\instagram\backend\routers\auth.js:62:48
(node:27268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id:
3)

Comment: Try `const { _id, name, email } = foundUser`

Comment: Yes already did but same error